# Don't work JavaFX textField getter, in another class return value is null

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have 2 classes
first class is controller

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextField myText;

    public TextField getMyText() {
        return myText;
    }
}
```

and second class

```
public class Print {
    private static Controller controller = new Controller();

    public void print() {
    System.out.println(controller.getMyText().getText());
    }
}
```

I enter a value in the textField and code throws exception
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TextField.getText()" because the return value of "Controller.getMyText()" is null.

Why? Thanks.

in fxml `TextField fx:id="myText" /`

and if set

```
System.out.println(myText.getText());
```

in controller class all OK.

Comment: Only the controller instance managed by an `FXMLLoader` has its fields injected; you have to get the controller from the loader after calling the instance `load` method. Additionally, it does not make much sense to keep a static reference to an FXML controller.

Comment: You did not show much code, but looking at what you have, it appears to be bad coding structure/logic. I would suggest learning MVC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Your code CAN NOT work.

1. When you start your application your controller is generally null and all fields inside too.
2. When your application loads a Scene, then it checks if the Scene has a controller assigned.
3. If the Scene has a controller assigned, the application creates an instance of the assigned controller and assigns it to the Scene.
4. While creating the instance of the controller, it checks, if there are any fields with @FXML annotations.
5. For all @FXML annotated fields, there will be an instance created and assigned to that field. Until now, all fields are null.
6. If your Scene is gone, the garbage collector will destroy the controller, because it is not used anymore (sets it to null)

Why is your code not working although there is an @FXML annotation? Because the controller is not created by loading Scene, but by yourself in code. @FXML only works when loading a Scene.

**Solution 1 (Bad):**

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextField myText = new TextField();
}
```

This does "work" but it may not fit your needs.

**Solution 2 (Good):**

1. Learn object orientated programming
2. Never use static again until you really know what you are doing.
3. Lean JavaFX basics.
4. Rewrite your code.
5. Profit.

You will not get happy without that.

Comment: For all @FXML annotated fields, there will be an instance created and assigned to that field. Until now, all fields are null.

Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: This post is a bit inaccurate in its wording in places. E.g. *"3.  If the Scene has a controller assigned, the application creates an instance of the assigned controller and assigns it to the Scene."*. The controller is not an attribute of a `Scene`, and is not created by the `Application`. The controller is created (in usual usage) by the `FXMLLoader` during the call to `load()` and the `FXMLLoader` instance retains a reference to the controller, which can be retrieved with `loader.getController()`.

Comment: *"5. For all @FXML annotated fields, there will be an instance created and assigned to that field."*. Kind of, but again this is inaccurate. Instance are created for all [instance elements](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#class_instance_elements) in the FXML (regardless of whether or not there is a corresponding `@FXML`-annotated field in the controller, or even a controller at all. The `@FXML` annotation does not actually cause any classes to be instantiated; it just retains a reference to instances created during the load process.

Comment: *"6. If your Scene is gone, the garbage collector will destroy the controller"*. Not necessarily. The `FXMLLoader` explicitly retains a reference to the controller, so the controller can only be gc'd if there is no reference to the `FXMLLoader`. (In normal usual this is typically the case.) Additionally, if you declare controller method event handlers in the FXML, the element on which the handler is declared will implicitly retain a reference to the controller. So the controller being eligible for GC really has nothing to do with the `Scene`; it depends on references to the UI in the FXML.